# asp.net zoom in & Zoom out button Display

Tags: asp.net, button, zooming

I have designed an asp.net chart, Just I would like to display a Zoom-In & Zoom-Out button at right corner to the chart, to give the feasibility for the user to perform Zooming the chart.

Please any one could suggest, what kind of button display I have to put and how would be the zoom-in.click and Zoom-out.click methods?

Thanks In advance!

Comment: Answer Is     <img src="../images/ZoomOut.png" alt="Close" style="cursor: pointer;" />